# Setting the name on a CPanel Email

Tags: email

Is it possible to set the name on CPanel Email? I know that the service CPanel uses to send email might have a different name, but I wasn't able to figure out what this is. If anyone could tell me this, then I'd greatly appreciate this.

For example, if I had an email bsmith@gmail.com, I've seen that some emails display this as Bob Smith. How can I set this name?

Comment: Are you referring to the webmail client that cPanel might be using (eg. "horde", "roundcube", "SquirrelMail", etc.) or the contact name that cPanel would use to send notification emails?

Comment: @w3d: Ah, so you have to configure the name on the webmail client, not with cPanel itself? cPanel allows you to create the email addresses directly

Comment: If I'm following you then yes, on the webmail client. cPanel allows you to set up "email accounts" which are associated with an _email address_, not the "From" header, if that is what you are implying. (?) You set the "From" header in whatever email client (or _webmail_ client) you decide to use. AFAIK you can't send email directly from cPanel?

Comment: w3d is correct, you can setup [email accounts](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Email+Accounts) for your domain(s) via the cPanel control panel, but you would _compose_ an email, including the _from_ display name, using a client or webmail application. The exception is default mail account for the administrator entered during setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can set a display name in emails sent by cPanel webmail services like `Horde`, `RoundCube` or `SquirrelMail`.

When you login to your email account with your preferred mail service, navigate as per below instructions and then you can change the display name.

**1. Horde:** Options => Personal Information => Your full name

**2. RoundCube:** Settings => Identities => [email id] => Display Name

**3. SquirrelMail:** Options => Personal Information => Full Name